# MySQL multiple insert from single select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `stats` table in which daily traffic is logged with around 500,000 daily records inserted.
Structure of this table is like

```
id  | ip | url | date | country | referrer | type | rate | category |....
```

This table is ever increasing in size and I want to keep it for write operations only

I need to perform analytics on this table data and store result in other tables for reporting.

I am planning to store data as follows..

Table `stats_by_date` will have daily stats grouped by date.

Table `stats_by_country` will have daily stats grouped by country.

Table `stats_by_type` will have daily stats grouped by type.

Table `stats_by_category` will have daily stats grouped by category.

This way instead of 500,000 rows only 1 row will be there for every day except for country table where 250 rows will be there for every day.

I need to insert data in these tables from main table every half an hour.
I know I can insert data with multiple query like

```
INSERT INTO `stats_by_date` (id, ip, date, rate, type) 
(
SELECT id, COUNT(ip), date, rate, type FROM `stats`
WHERE date=today 
GROUP BY date
);

INSERT INTO `stats_by_type` (id, ip, date, rate, type) 
(
SELECT id, COUNT(ip), date, rate, type FROM `stats`
WHERE date=today 
GROUP BY type
);
```

In this way there will be at least 4 `INSERT` queries which will read same data from main table and inserting based on `GROUP BY`.

I want to read from main table only once and insert in all other tables.
To the best of my knowledge to achieve this I know I have to make `TEMPORARY TABLE` in which I have to store data from main table and then from this `TEMPORARY TABLE` I can do multiple `INSERT`.

I want to know is there any other efficient way to do this, Can it be done in a single `SELECT` some how?

Please see and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

500,000 rows every day is a respectable amount of data.  This process would normally be handled using triggers on the primary table -- the trigger would do the insert of the new data.

Your `date` column suggests that you have a batch upload process. 
 If so, you can add the rows into the summary tables after doing the uploads.  This is much simpler than messing around with triggers, which will be doing zillions of updates on the summary tables.

Comment: The data in stats table(primary) is daily visits to web-pages, I don't have batch upload process, but I will be using time based triggers to insert data into summary tables.

Comment: @TallboY . . . Time-based *events* are a much better idea than triggers for each insert.

Comment: So there is no way to do these `INSERTS` in single `SELECT` some how? is it possible?

Comment: @TallboY . . . Not in MySQL.  Postgres has such a construct, but not MySQL.